# Why to specify width or height in <object> tag to display SVG in IE11?

Tags: svg, internet-explorer-11

I have a svg file i am displaying it in mozilla and chrome. It displayed correctly in ubuntu os. When i tested it in IE11 in windows 7 OS the image is dispalying very small. If i give width or height to  tag then it is displaying properly.

```
   <object data="image.svg" type="image/svg+xml" width="100%"></object>
```